# go and mysql and cloneTLSConfig

Tags: mysql, go

when I use go mysql. i got this problem. 
undefined: cloneTLSConfig
I don't know how to fix this problem.
here it is my code.

```
package main

import(
        "database/sql"

        _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

         "fmt"
         "log"
)

func main() {
    db,err=sql.Open("mysql","root:19920211@tcp(localhost:3306)/names?charset=utf8" )

    if err!=nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Well done")

    defer db.Close()
}
```

When building:

```
$ go build
# github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/utils.go:81: undefined: cloneTLSConfig
```

Comment: You haven't included all your code in the answer. cloneTLSConfig is defined here in the http/transport pkg, you probably don't need it: https://tip.golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L2014 Include all code in your question as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of **golang** (<= 1.6.4) and this is no longer supported by the **go-sql-driver/mysql** maintainer.

You have to upgrade your golang version or use another mysql driver, like [ziutek/mymysql](https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql).

See [this link](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/720) for more detail.